# make -j 8 g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, g++, mesos

When I deploy Apache Mesos on Ubuntu12.04, I follow the official document, in step "make -j 8" I'm getting this error in the console:

```
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [slave/containerizer/mesos/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-containerizer.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mv -f log/.deps/liblog_la-log.Tpo log/.deps/liblog_la-log.Plo
mv -f slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-docker.Tpo slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-docker.Plo
mv -f log/.deps/liblog_la-consensus.Tpo log/.deps/liblog_la-consensus.Plo

mv -f slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-external_containerizer.Tpo slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-external_containerizer.Plo
mv -f log/.deps/liblog_la-coordinator.Tpo log/.deps/liblog_la-coordinator.Plo
mv -f slave/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-slave.Tpo slave/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-slave.Plo
mv -f master/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-master.Tpo master/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-master.Plo
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Mesos/mesos/build/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Mesos/mesos/build/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

what should I do?

Comment: Congratulations, you found a bug in your compiler. Consider submitting a bug report as requested...

Comment: @nneoneo, True enough.  When he asked, "What should I do?", I believe he meant, "... to get it working?"  I would suggest running "make -j 8 VERBOSE=1" just to see if anything on the g++ command line does not look like what you expect.  If you're lucky, you'll find a clue about your next step.

Comment: Also, drop the `"-j 8"`. That simply causes `make` to parallelize the build which isn't going to make anything clearer.

Comment: When i make firstly, it costs me 3 hours. Then I run make -j 8  second time, this time it complete faster(server minutes ).But I run the infra step(make check), i get another error:

Comment: g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [slave/containerizer/mesos/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-containerizer.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mv -f log/.deps/liblog_la-log.Tpo log/.deps/liblog_la-log.Plo
mv -f slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-docker.Tpo slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-docker.Plo
mv -f log/.deps/liblog_la-consensus.Tpo log/.deps/liblog_la-consensus.Plo

Comment: mv -f slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-external_containerizer.Tpo slave/containerizer/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-external_containerizer.Plo
mv -f log/.deps/liblog_la-coordinator.Tpo log/.deps/liblog_la-coordinator.Plo
mv -f slave/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-slave.Tpo slave/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-slave.Plo
mv -f master/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-master.Tpo master/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-master.Plo
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Mesos/mesos/build/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Mesos/mesos/build/src'

Comment: make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: My gcc and g++ version is 4.9.2.

Comment: @Gil Hamilton I add VERBOS=1 params to make , and get the same result.

Comment: Try `make -j 2`. Perhaps you don't have enough RAM for `-j 8` and a compilation process was hit by the infamous *memory overcommit* (which you should disable on your machine)

Comment: @pugna, please check that you typed `VERBOSE`, not `VERBOS`.  The option won't fix the problem, but will show you everything `make` put on the `g++` command line.

Comment: @pugna First, as I recommended earlier, get rid of `-j 8` for the reason that @BasileStarynkevitch notes above. Second, submitting your bug report in comments here on stackoverflow is not going to help you or anyone else. Go to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/

Comment: I solved cleaning up space  ( dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile  bs=1M ) and then removing the zerofile

Answer (score 162):

Try running (just after the failure) `dmesg`.

Do you see a line like this?

```
Out of memory: Kill process 23747 (cc1plus) score 15 or sacrifice child
Killed process 23747, UID 2243, (cc1plus) total-vm:214456kB, anon-rss:178936kB, file-rss:5908kB
```

Most likely that is your problem. Running make -j 8 runs lots of process which use more memory. The problem above occurs when your system runs out of memory. In this case rather than the whole system falling over, the operating systems runs a process to score each process on the system. The one that scores the highest gets killed by the operating system to free up memory. If the process that is killed is cc1plus, gcc (perhaps incorrectly) interprets this as the process crashing and hence assumes that it must be a compiler bug. But it isn't really, the problem is the OS killed cc1plus, rather than it crashed.

If this is the case, you are running out of memory. So run perhaps make -j 4 instead. This will mean fewer parallel jobs and will mean the compilation will take longer but hopefully will not exhaust your system memory.

Comment: Thanks, `dmesg` show the error. It seems `j4` will got `out of memory`.

Comment: I had the same error - even with -j 1. What helped me was to kill another (unneeded) process that took a big chunk of RAM

Comment: Thank you . This was the cause in my case. upvoted.

Answer (score 55):

*(Might be a memory issue)*

For anybody still struggling with this (over 2 years after the question was asked), there's [this trick](https://cryptocurrencytalk.com/topic/14840-how-to-solve-g-internal-compiler-error-killed-program-cc1plus/) on CryptoCurrencyTalk that seems to make it work.

For convenience I'm pasting it here:

Run these (adjust `bs=` and `count=` to the amount of swap you want)

- `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=64M count=16`
- `sudo mkswap /swapfile`
- `sudo swapon /swapfile`

That should let you compile your code. **But** make sure you then revert the `swapon` after compilation, with these:

- `sudo swapoff /swapfile`
- `sudo rm /swapfile`

Comment: Sad for the users under limitations of OpenVZ VPS Servers. This "trick" will not work. The Swap technique is not available for individual VPSs, only for the main System :-(

Comment: this only adds 64*16 = 1024 MB of swap, not very much.  My compilation required 8 GB, so why not set bs=1G if you have the space

Answer (score 20):

check if your CentOS installation already has swap enabled by typing:

```
sudo swapon --show
```

If the output is empty, it means that your system does not have swap space enabled.

**Create a swap file**

1.create a file which will be used as a swap space. bs is the size of one block. count is num of blocks. it will get 1024K * 1M = 1G space.

**`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576`**

2.Ensure that only the root user can read and write the swap file:

`sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`

3.set up a Linux swap area on the file

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

4.activate the swap

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

5."sudo swapon --show" or "sudo free -h" you will see the swap space.

Answer (score 2):

This was the clue in my scenario (compiling mesos on CentOS 7) on an AWS EC2 instance.

I fixed it by increasing memory and cpu to at least 4GiB and 2 vCPUs.