# grpc build stuck on virtual machine

Tags: c++, ubuntu, grpc

I'm following steps from https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/ and I was doing make -j at step 3. Then, my whole screen of the vm got frozen except the mouse. After a while, like several minutes, I received several fatal errors indicating the build failed. I have attached 2 screenshots. One is from the state the screen is frozen and one is the afterwards with errors. Thanks.

screen froze at 46%

[image]

the fatal errors
[image]

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887143/make-j-8-g-internal-compiler-error-killed-program-cc1plus

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried dmesg and it shows the out of memory message. I'm thinking about running make-j with a specific number. And I'm still hoping for some other people coming up with suggestions.

Comment: No, running `make -j` on a smallish VM is a recipe for disaster. Stick to `make -j4` or something small.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have 8GB  memory and 80GB disk with 4 cpu cores for my vm. I was surprised it ran out of memory.

Comment: Mine with 32GiB ran out of memory, lol

Answer (score 0):

The original issue is resolved by specifying make -j4 as it is an out of memory issue.