# AWS SDK For CPP make stuck at 88%

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run the AWS SDK for CPP and looks like for some reason after the make stage it stuck on:

```
[ 88%] Built target aws-cpp-sdk-core
[ 88%] Building CXX object aws-cpp-sdk-s3/CMakeFiles/aws-cpp-sdk-s3.dir/ub_S3.cpp.o
```

My CMAKE version is 3.21.7
I cloned the library from here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.
Then I used this command:

```
cmake ../aws-sdk-cpp -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ -DBUILD_ONLY="s3"
```

Then used "make" but looks like it got stuck.
Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably out of memory. Running dmesg right after that would indicate that.

I had the same issue with a similar cmake incantation also specifying just S3, running on an Amazon Linux 2 instance. It was in fact exactly the same, 88% and on ub_S3.cpp. And repeatable.

My solution was to add swap space to the VM. There are examples at [this stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47374605/21045068). Specifically, I did:

```html
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576
  sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
```

And that 1 GB swap was enough for making to work.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem.
Do you know what is the maximum size to swap?

Comment: If you mean the most you can allocate to swap, I assume that would be limited by the S3 instance.